# Having trouble printing Null

Tags: c++

So I want my output to put out NA, In a certain case. However I am confused on how to do that. I was thinking a if statement similar to what I use before in my code.
Output:

```
Input the length of three sides of the triangle: 5 5 5 
Enter whether the triangle is filled (1) or not (0): 0
 Color: 
Area: 10.8253
Perimeter: 15
```

So if the user inputs 0, whether or not the triangle is filled, I want Color to output N/A.
My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
//triangle class toperform all the operation on a triangle
class Triangle
{
    double side1, side2, side3; //private variable storing sides of triangle

public:
    bool filled;
    string color;
    //default constructor
    Triangle()
    {
        this->side1 = 1.0;
        this->side2 = 1.0;
        this->side3 = 1.0;
    }
    //constructor two initialize sides of tiangle with the given value
    Triangle(double one, double two, double three)
    {
        this->side1 = one;
        this->side2 = two;
        this->side3 = three;
    }
    //function to return perimiter of triangle
    double getPerimeter()
    {
        return this->side1 + this->side2 + this->side3;
    }
    //function to return area of triangle
    double getArea()
    {
        double p = getPerimeter() / 2;
        double area = p * (p - this->side1) * (p - this->side2) * (p - this->side3);
        return sqrt(area);
    }
};
int main()
{
    double a, b, c;
    int filled;
    string col = "";
    cout << "Input the length of three sides of the triangle: ";
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    Triangle triObj(a, b, c);
    cout << "Enter whether the triangle is filled (1) or not (0): ";
    cin >> filled;
    triObj.filled = filled;
    if (filled == 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter the colour of the triangle: ";
        cin >> col;
        triObj.color = col;
    }

    if (filled == 0)
    {
        //Need help with this
    }

    cout << "Color: " << triObj.color;
    cout << "\nArea: " << triObj.getArea();
    cout << "\nPerimeter: " << triObj.getPerimeter() << '\n';
    cout << "\nWas the triangle filled?: ";
    if (triObj.filled)
        cout << "True\n";
    else
        cout << "False\n";

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use: triObj.color = "NA"? Or, initialize **col** to "NA" instead of an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way would be to do this:

```cpp
if (col == "0")
  triObj.color = "N/A";
else
  triObj.color = col;
```

Here's a shorter, ready-to-use rewrite of your `main` function that incorporates this fix:

```cpp
int main()
{
    double a,b,c;
    cout << "Input the length of three sides of the triangle: ";
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    Triangle triObj{ a, b, c };
    cout << "Enter whether the triangle is filled (1) or not (0): ";
    cin >> triObj.filled;
    cout << "Enter the colour of the triangle: ";
    cin >> triObj.color;
    if (triObj.color == "0")
        triObj.color = "N/A";
    cout 
      << "Color: " << triObj.color << '\n'
      << "Area: " << triObj.getArea() << '\n'
      << "Perimeter: " << triObj.getPerimeter() << '\n'
      << "Was the triangle filled?: " << boolalpha << triObj.filled << noboolalpha << '\n';
}
```